# Plus removed other parts of string and keeps only the matching

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

This is my code:

```
const prepD = {
            name: 'John Smith',
            objArr: [
                'test',
                'Lorem ipsum ' + check() ? 'true' : 'false' + ' rest of text'
            ]
        };
```

In my case when `check()` returns `true` I get this output only:

`true`, while I should get `Lorem Ipsum true rest of text`.

Why does it remove the remaining of the concatenated text and how to keep full text if the statement is `true`?

Thank you/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the condition with `()` to convert it to an expression:

```
(check() ? 'true' : 'false')
```

Running example:

```js
function check(){return true;}
const prepD = {
  name: 'John Smith',
  objArr: [
    'test',
    'Lorem ipsum ' + (check() ? 'true' : 'false') + ' rest of text'
  ]
};

console.log(prepD.objArr);
```

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried it..

`'Lorem ipsum ' + (check() ? 'true' : 'false') + ' rest of text'` for some reason gives me 'false', though it should be `true`. So for some reason it validates second statement as true..

Comment: make sure that `check` returns true then. as you can see in the snippet i posted it runs as expected.